# vuejs on app mount wait for pinia Store to be installed

Tags: vue.js, pinia

i'm kind of struggling with what i thought could be an easy task.

My app should at App.vue mount proceed to some checks (api tokens and so on) and also put some data's into my Pinia store i found out that pinia took a bit of time to initialise and my store updates never get putted into my store ( the action of check and update store is triggerd before my store had time to be installed)

Do you guys have some workaround or advices on how to handle it.
i want something like

app.vue

```
async mounted(){
    await '<wait for my pinia store to be installed>'
    myUdpatefunction() // => function that act and update some data's into pinia store
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is "wait for my pinia store to be installed" exactly? Do not mount the component you expect to rely on the result of async operation until it's completed. It's unknown what's your case and which approaches are applicable (router hook, suspense, etc)

Comment: Under normal circumstances,Pinia is running at main.js and its before App.vue  created, I gusset your Pinia contains async codes, you need remove  them to other places(such as app.vue)

Comment: @floprm can you share your main.js/main.ts? That will determine if Pinia is imported correctly or not.